# Failed to set session cookie phpmyadmin

Tags: php, nginx, cookies, phpmyadmin, nginx-config

I configure my phpadmin with nginx and I have a problem to login. my phpadmin version 4.9.5 my php version PHP 7.4.3 .

it work when I try to change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php with 'http' or 'config'

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';

but with cookie $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; not working and return Failed

to set session cookie Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS .I search I

found clear browser ...but it is not a solution

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I use  HTTPS  for my server but  I try with other in local (localhost) not working for the both

Comment: Can you try with an up-to-date version of PHP and phpMyAdmin?

Comment: same think not working for phpmyadmin 5.1.1 and php8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the extension Selenuim IDE in my browsers google Chrome and Mozilla firefox. now it work when I disabled the extension